# Trigger to loop and send incremental email based on condition

Tags: oracle, trigger, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a requirement in Oracle apex to implement dynamic approval workflow in issue tracker.

I am trying to write a trigger for the same as below. I need to further modify it so that it runs sequentially.
i.e. When an issue is raised in related dept, it passes through multiple approval levels.

Trigger 1 sends email to first approver for approval.
When the approver logs in to approve, set p_it_issues.APPROVE_THIS='Y1', the next trigger sets p_it_issues.approved=1 to show it has passed first level. 
The second trigger sends email notification to second approver as well. (all code mentioned below for reference).

But due to varying levels of approval this would means i will have to create more and more triggers.
Is there a way to combine this so that it would keep incrementing and sending approvals from p_it_people.approver='Approver 1'.to..'Ápprover n' based on approval_level per department? HR department has n approval levels (p_it_departments.approval_level=n , so it would only send it to the n approvers in p_it_people table with Approver column set as Approver 1 .. n respectively?

I need to make this more dynamic, so that in approve_this we have only Y and N. 
And both Approvers with Approve 1 select Y in approve_This and then it would move to Approver 2

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. Could you please have a look at [ask] in the help centre and possibly the [mcve] post on the meta site? It's hard to follow what you are trying to achieve and if you could explain it with more steps, then we might be able to assist you. Thanks.

Comment: The trigger mentioned is when an issue is raised, it would go to person with approver='Approver 1', he is first approver. When he logs into application and sets p_it_issues.is_approved='Y', then email would shoot to p_it_people.Approver='Approver 2' . He would again log in, set p_it_issues.is_approved='Y' and email would shoot to p_it_people.Approver='Approver 3' . There could be more than one person with  p_it_people.Approver='Approver 1' or 2 or 3. So all would need to approve it and set Y .

Comment: What table are you going to store the approvals by the various `P_IT_PEOPLE`? If "there could be more than one person with p_it_people.Approver='Approver 1' " then you need another table to record each of the '`Y`" approvals for a particular level.  Think through that, including how to store the various levels of approvals, then [edit] your answer to include your previous comments about approval clarifications, so other users won't have to read all the comments to understand your question, and information on your new table to store the approvals.

Comment: Yes, P_IT_ISSUES has approve_this column. So as of now when Approver 1 sets approver_THis='Y1', column Approved is set to 1 showing 1st level validation is passed. Similarly when Approver 2 set approve_this='Y2', approved is set to 2 (trigger updates this on basis of approve_This value). I need to make this more dynamic, so that in approve_this we have only Y and N. And both Approvers with Approve 1 select Y in approve_This and then it would move to Approver 2.

Comment: I realised this question has become to clumsy and confusing. i have created new post. Please spare time and take a look at this post which is hopefully clearer and concise. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/267432/oracle-apex-shot-email-when-approvers-approve-and-issue-using-triggers-and-apex

Comment: No it doesn''t. I  understand workflow concept is essential but at current stage i need help with  the second trigger as mentioned making it dynamic if possible.

Comment: This is a small project and it is just a temporary requirement after which it will be built on a large scale from scratch. I need to do this temporarily on immediate basis